# How to ask "anybody/anyone/somebody/someone" questions in Chinese?

Tags: translation, grammar, word-choice, vocabulary

For example, how do you translate, "Does anybody/anyone in the dorm have a vacuum I could use?" Or, "Can I borrow somebody's/someone's shoes?"

I don't know how to say these types of questions that ask "anybody" "anyone" "somebody" or "someone."

Would appreciate help!! :))) Thanks!

Comment: search web using e.g."英文语法：anybody, somebody", get many results, e.g. http://www.yingyu.com/e/20140812/53e971873c6a9.shtml

Comment: dictionary:任何人／某人 anybody/somebody
（１）在宿舍里有人有吸尘器我能用吗？ （２）可以借用某人的鞋子吗？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want '有人‘ or ’谁‘。

Does anybody know the answer?
有人知道答案吗？
谁知道答案吗？

Someone must know the answer！
肯定有人知道答案！

Does anybody/anyone in the dorm have a vacuum I could use?
我们宿舍有人可以借给我一台吸尘机吗？

"Can I borrow somebody's/someone's shoes?" 
我能借一下别人的鞋子吗？
我能不能借一下谁的鞋子？

May I borrow someone's jacket?
我可以借别人的夹克吗？
我可否向别人借一下夹克？

Who can lend me a jacket?
谁能借我一件夹克衫？

Who can lend me a vacuum cleaner?
谁能借我一台吸尘器？有人可以借我一台吸尘器吗？

（Don't borrow other people's shoes, you might get a foot infection!)